# Null Reference in my Structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework and C# to build my database behind my current MVC web application

I have 3 objects that we will call Request, File and Item.

Each object have their own properties, but they have relationships with each others

Request has a list of Files and a list of Items
File has a list of Items and a parent Request
Item has a parent File and a parent request

The problem is that when I create a new File and add it to the list of File of my Request, the parent Request of my file is Null. The same happens with every other realtionships I have.

Is there a setting or a way of writting my entity framework classes that I'm not doing correctly?

Here's the example for my File class

```
public class myFile
{
    public myFile()
    {
        this.Items = new List<Item>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int myFileID { get; set; }
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }


    public virtual Request Request { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: where in the code are you assigning or giving the current request a value the values of which you are showing in code by default will be null or string.empty etc...

Comment: @DJKRAZE I create a new File object, fill in the name, and then I add it to the File list in my Request object. I thought that would set my file's Object automaticaly, but it doesn't seem to.